# Issues with extended mapi wrapper for c#:

Tags: c#, mapi

I have used mapi wrapper for c# (by Noel Dillabough - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx).

I found few issues:

1. AddAttachment method execution operation takes a long time.
2. After ShowForm method executed and mail sent window is open,
   when close the main application (but mail sent window still stays open) i
   get the error message that says: "Attempted to read or write
   protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
   corrupt.".

Can somebody help?
thanks!

Comment: you could try http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm - if it shows the same behaviour then the problem is on the MAPI-side of things...

Comment: You really need to step into the wrapper code and show the MAPI calls that cause the problem - or use a wrapper (such as Redemption) that supports C#.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should know when using Extended MAPI .Net wrappers is that their are all fundamentally flawed.  That's according to guidance from Microsoft.

MAPI is really old code.  It uses it's own memory management system which is incompatible with .Net's memory management.

Supposedly, a while back there was talk to make the MAPI subsystem .Net compatible but that never got off the ground.

See this post for the full account

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2009/04/03/mapi-and-net.aspx